# Group two areas in Mapify

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website where I need to use responsive image mappings.

I switched to mapify.js (http://etiennemartin.ca/mapify/) and I can't find any way to group two areas to have a common rollover effect.

For the sake of example, let's say that I have a double door and there's a pillar (for some reason) in its center. I want to higlight both doors but not the pillar.

In maphighlight.js I could use `groupBy` to group two areas.

I've been struggling for the past two hours searching on SO as well as looking in Mapify's core but couldn't find anything.

How can I achieve this with Mapify?

Comment: The github page states how to do this.  I can't stand people that are too lazy to read even the first page of documentation.

Comment: As I said above, I've been struggling with this for two hours now. Yeah, I missed the github button, that doesn't mean that I didn't researched the problem. It's 4 am here but by the way you talk to people I'm sure you're very productive at any hour. Thank you for answering.